# Document jQuery widgets using @ngdoc

Tags: jquery, ngdoc

How do I document jQuery widgets using `gulp-ngdoc`? I have something like this:

```
/**
 * @ngdoc widgets
 * @name XXX.YYY
 * @description
 * This is a jQueryUI widget to provide...
 * 
 * @namespace XXX.YYY
 */
```

...and I get following error: `[Error: Don't know how to format @ngdoc: widgets]`

Comment: According to the [docs](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Writing-AngularJS-Documentation) I don't see `@namespace` anywhere.. maybe causing the issue?

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work :/